# problems with data in python

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have code in django:

```
for i in range(int(cac)):
     print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") - datetime.timedelta(minutes=i)
```

and have some of this errors :

```
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

or

```
type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'mktime'
```

or somethings else.

I try few examples:

```
import datetime
import time
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
```

or

```
from datetime import *
from time import *
```

explain me what I do wrong? 
thanks

Comment: It looks like you must have `from datetime import datetime`, in which case use just `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Install bpython, it's an alternative console with good autocomplete. It will help you see the hierarchy of modules to solve these types of problems.

Comment: i try, and have error "global name 'time' is not defined" in string : "time_begin = time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()) - 3600 "

Comment: did you miss `import time`?

Comment: try too) and have "type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'"

Comment: `import time` and `from datetime import datetime` is what you need based on the line above

Comment: thanks for the help, but have this error "type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'" and that's why i don't understand what i do wrong

Comment: see my first comment. You really should spend the time to understand why you're getting these errors though

Comment: tried this one? import datetime.datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all your imports. If you import in models like

> from datetime import datetime

and then import

> from .models import *

so you will have errors like this. Check all your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
for i in range(int(cac)):
    print (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```